# Can I use two dropdownlists with a DetailsView Control to insert new record

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, detailview

I don't think this question has been asked before (or at least I couldn't find a similar question), if so my apologies.

I have a asp.net web page I am building that has two dropdownlists bound to two different object data sources. The first ddl displays a list of customer names and once selected the second ddl list displays the product names that the customer has purchased. The page is designed to insert an "incident" record so that once the customer and product is chosen I like to use a detailview (with default mode set to INSERT and bound to a third object data source (incidents table)) to create a new record.

My question then, is it possible to somehow grab the values from the two ddl's and have those values used along with the detailsview insertitem templates to insert a new record?

Comment: Of course you can, why would you think you could not? Which is to say, have you tried and if not, why?

I'm presuming I must be missing part of the question. Scoped controls are pretty basic stuff with Applications like this, so I'm guessing you encountered some issue. Maybe more information would help me understand what's blocking you.

Comment: Perhaps it mainly because I am a noob and still studying web application programming. I tried putting the ddl's into the insertitem templates but when I do, my second ddl that is bound to value of the first ddl fails to populate, because the select statement cannot retrieve records from the products table without the customerID (value from ddlCustomers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Trap the selecteditemchanged event on DDL1, in your handler, update the query for ddl2. hope this helps. as always, communication is the hardest thing we do, so it's completely possible i have miss interpreted your question :)

Comment: Appreciate it, sounds like that will work. I'll research how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new web developer like me then the following links can help you correct error in the process of putting the ddl's into the insertitem templates, in case your process has error.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1jdrRoqJ6w

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03stYtlAemU

I hope this will help.

Comment: There are several tutorials on msdn on different topics of asp.net that can help you understand it well   http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos